# Break up address string into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a street address string pulling into a table, that is separated by char(10). I am trying to separate the string so that I can map that field into another system, that has Addressline1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3. I've been working with the following:

```
  ,case when CHARINDEX(char(10),[BillingStreet])= 0 then BillingStreet else substring(BillingStreet,1,charindex(char(10),BillingStreet)-1) end AddressLine1
  ,case when CHARINDEX(char(10),[BillingStreet])= 0 then '' else substring(BillingStreet,charindex(char(10),BillingStreet)+1,charindex(char(10),BillingStreet)-1) end AddressLine2
  ,case when CHARINDEX(char(10),[BillingStreet])= 0 then '' else reverse(substring(reverse(BillingStreet),0,charindex(char(10),reverse(BillingStreet)))) end AddressLine3
```

My issue is that if an address does not have a 3rd char(1), then my columns AddressLine2 & AddressLine3 will be the same. Should I use a different case statement on AddressLine3 or be using a different substring statement?

Sample street address:
1234 Main Street
Unit 123
BOX 123

```
Desired output:
Addressline1 = 1234 Main Street
Addressline2 = Unit 123
Addressline3 = BOX 123
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: updated with sample

Answer (score 1):

If functions are an option, the you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string). The solution below uses no predefined function. It does include a recursive common table expression.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyData
(
  Id int,
  MyAddress nvarchar(200)
);

insert into MyData (Id, MyAddress) values
(1, 'address line 1' + char(10) + 'address line 2' + char(10) + 'address line 3'),
(2, 'short address' + char(10) + 'with only 2 lines'),
(3, '1234 Main Street' + char(10) + 'Unit 123' + char(10) + 'BOX 123');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as (
  select md.MyAddress, 1 as Starts, charindex(char(10), md.MyAddress) as Pos, 1 as RowNum
  from MyData md
    union all
  select cte.MyAddress, cte.Pos + 1, charindex(char(10), cte.MyAddress, cte.Pos + 1), RowNUm+1
  from cte
  where cte.Pos > 0
),
split as
(
  select cte.MyAddress,
         cte.RowNum,
         substring(cte.MyAddress, cte.Starts, case when cte.Pos > 0 then cte.Pos-cte.Starts else len(cte.MyAddress) end) as Line
  from cte
)
select p.MyAddress,
       p.[1] as Line1,
       p.[2] as Line2,
       p.[3] as Line3
from split s
pivot (max(s.Line) for s.RowNum in ([1], [2], [3])) p;
```

Result and intermediate result: see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=393c0efab66a3e81d1715a27ac9a2fb8).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using PARSENAME function ? Please find below the snippet

```
    Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(BillingStreet), ' ', '.'), 1)) As Address1
  , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(BillingStreet), ' ', '.'), 2)) As Address2
  , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(BillingStreet), ' ', '.'), 3)) As Address3
```

Comment: I'm just getting null values

Comment: `char(10)` is a line feed character and not a space `' '`. This answer needs some tweaking.

Comment: Also, ParseName will only work well if the different parts are no longer than 128 chars.

Comment: I just gave the snippet , you need to modify it according to your needs. I have used the same for a similar requirement.